# Ideal value for Kafka Connect Distributed tasks.max configuration setting?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am looking to productionize and deploy my Kafka Connect application.  However, there are two questions I have about the tasks.max setting which is required and of high importance but details are vague for what to actually set this value to.

If I have a topic with n partitions that I wish to consume data from and write to some sink (in my case, I am writing to S3), what should I set tasks.max to?  Should I set it to n?  Should I set it to 2n?  Intuitively it seems that I'd want to set the value to n and that's what I've been doing.

What if I change my Kafka topic and increase partitions on the topic?  I will have to pause my Kafka Connector and increase the tasks.max if I set it to n?  If I have set a value of 2n, then my connector should automatically increase the parallelism it operates?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In a Kafka Connect sink, the tasks are essentially consumer threads and receive partitions to read from. If you have 10 partitions and have `tasks.max` set to 5, each task with receive 2 partitions to read from and track the offsets. If you have configured `tasks.max` to a number above the partition count Connect will launch a number of tasks equal to the partitions of the topics it's reading.

If you change the partition count of the topic you'll have to relaunch your connect task, if `tasks.max` is still greater than the partition count, Connect will start that many tasks.

edit, just discovered `ConnectorContext`: https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/connector/ConnectorContext.html

The connector will have to be written to include this but it looks like Connect has the ability to reconfigure a connector if there's a topic change (partitions added/removed).

Comment: What if we are running Kafka connect in Distributed Mode with 2 machine. How consumer tasks(thread) are being spawned and get associated with worker machine if tasks are greater/less than the partitions ?

Comment: @Vivek, Distributed mode will distribute the tasks as evenly as possible on all running instances.

Answer (score 4):

We had a problem with the distribution of the workload between the Kafka-Connect(5.1.2) instances, caused by the high number of `tasks.max` than the number of partitions.

In our case, there were 10 Kafka Connect tasks and 3 partitions of the topic which is to be consumed. 3 of those 10 workers are assigned to the 3 partitions of the topic and the other 7 are not assigned to any partitions(which is expected) but the Kafka Connect were distributing the tasks evenly, without considering their workload. So we were ending up with a task distribution to our instances where some instances are staying idle( because they are not assigned to any unempty worker ) or some instances are working more than the others.

To come up with the issue, we set `tasks.max` equal to number of partitions of our topics.

It is really unexpected for us to see that Kafka Connect does not consider tasks' assignments while rebalancing. Also, I couldn't find any documentation for the `tasks.max` setting.