# Ideal value for Kafka Connect tasks.max relative to number of CPU cores?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I understand that ideally tasks.max = # of partitions for max throughput. But how many tasks per cpu core is ideal?

Comment: Please refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42030617)

Comment: This doesn't say anything about cpu cores though

Comment: Ideal? One per core, seems obvious. Same could be said for any multithreaded application